# Sphinx doesn't return matches when querying with Nodejs and limestone

Tags: node.js, sphinx

I have been trying Nodejs and limestone for querying sphinx documents. But it is returning sphinx attribute and fields only

My file content as follows,

```
var limestone = require("limestone").SphinxClient();
limestone.connect("192.168.1.113:3312", function(err) {
    if (!err) {

        limestone.query({query: "test", maxmatches:1, indexes:"phoneindex"}, function(err, answer){
            if (!err) {
                console.log("Extended search for 'test' yielded " + answer.match_count + " results: " + JSON.stringify(answer));
                limestone.disconnect();
            }else{
                console.log("Connected ERR: "+err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Output as follows,

```
Extended search for 'test' yielded 0 results: {"status":0,"num_fields":2,"fields":[{"name":"name"},{"name":"phone"}],"attributes":[],"matches":[],"num_attrs":0,"match_count":0,"id64":0,"total":0,"total_found":0,"msecs":0,"words_count":1,"words":{"test":{"docs":0,"hits":0}}}
```

The phoneindex has 4 values, but in the above result the matches is empty. 
Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue.

wildcard is not enabled in the indexes. But the limestone.js, querying the word "test". So the node.js & limestone not yielding any result for me. So i added 
(not proper way) `query["query"] = "";` line no: 284 in the limestone.js . Now it is working fine for me.

Thanks for the great module **[limestone](http://github.com/kurokikaze/limestone/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you specify

```
maxmatches:1
```

? Pretty sure that will cause issues.

But otherwise, have you tried the query outside of node/limestone. Eg using the 'search' command line tool.

Are your indexes built correctly. Does 'indextool --dumpheader' show valid data?

What about using test.pl/.php/.py in the api/ folder of the sphinx installation?

Another area ot check is the sphinx query log. (if you have it enabled)

... using these tools, will help narrow it down to the cause.

Comment: i have 15 indexes in my sphinx. So i changed the limestone query as follows,

limestone.query({query: "test", indexes:"weddingpics_new"}, function(err, answer){

For the above query, i got matches and everything working fine here. But if i changed the query / indexname,  then i does not return any matches. Any suggestion on this please..

Note: i have executed indextool --dumpheader doesn't have any major difference in the both indexes(phoneindex and weddingpics_new)

Comment: Maybe there is nothing that actully matches 'test' in phoneindex. --- Try a differnt query :)   Also try --dumphitlist